# setting VScode extension to its defalut settings

Tags: vscode-extensions

how can I bring all the settings of an extension to its default?
would uninstalling them and then re-installing do the trick?

From time to time I'm playing around with extensions settings, and sometimes I mess things up.
Now I'm having problems while compiling my code with the Calva extension, and I would like to know if it has something to do with the changes I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to reset all settings to their default value, but...

You can see very easy, which settings you have changed. Open the settings with `CTRL+,` and on the top right of the search bar you can set the filter to show only modified items or enter `@modified` in the search bar. All modified settings are displayed with a blue bar in front of it.

[image]

Or if you have changed the settings in the workspace, you can see all modified settings in the file settings.json

[image]

Pictures taken from [VScode Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_changing-a-setting)